# bring back the shadow of context menu

Tags: unity, context-menu, shadow

How do I bring back the shadow of context? There is not outline shadow around context menu in all software I use. (In some software this is very annoying to find difference between background and the context menu)

[image]

Comment: Your desktop environment is Unity, right? Can you remember having changed anything that might have caused this?

Comment: @ByteCommander I am using Unity DE. Last time I installed (and the removed) KDE DE

Comment: Wanna try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`?

Comment: @ByteCommander I reinstalled ubuntu-desktop and logged out and logged in again; no use

Comment: Maybe related: http://askubuntu.com/q/37654/367990 and http://askubuntu.com/q/95462/367990.

Comment: @ByteCommander nope these all speak about window shadow

Answer (score 0):

Run **CompizConfig Settings Manager** by executing `ccsm`.

Select the category **Desktop** and then click on the <kbd>**Ubuntu Unity Plugin**</kbd>.

Switch to the tab **Decorations** to get the settings shown in the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]

If your settings differ from the ones I have, you should try applying those default ones to your system. Maybe you need to log out and back in for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I have those settings already

Comment: Hmm... Wrong guess then. I'll see if I find more settings.

Comment: Maybe "Override Theme"?

Comment: @Takkat not working; I had that thing checked already